# How to disable a rails form input without creating vulnerability.

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have an input field that I have set to be disabled on the front end using the code below. The issue is that if the user modifies the code in the browser they can change it to be whatever they want. How to I prevent this on the backend?

```
<input type="text" class="text party_name disabled-textfield" id="party_name" name="party_name" disabled="disabled" value="<%= @current_user.name %>" />
```

Comment: Why are you paying any attention to this field when you're receiving a POST request? Just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you handle this with [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) where you don't blindly accept anything you're given. You write a method like this:

```
def input_params
  params.permit(:editable_name, :favorite)
end
```

There you'd enumerate the allowed fields and the rest are simply ignored. I'm not sure what other parameters you have, but you can split them out in to "required" and "permitted" groups. These can even vary depending on privilege or ownership of the record in question.

Answer (score -3):

http://jsfiddle.net/vfvsLj0n/

```
$('.party_name.disabled-textfield').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Is this a possibility for you?

Comment: This isn't a client-side problem and no amount of JavaScript can fix a broken API.